# C# SQLite Extensions InsertWithChildren doesn't work why?

Tags: c#, sqlite

i have a Problem with my SQLite-Database. I use the SQLite.Net and SQLiteNetExtensions PCL NuGets and followed this excample: [Link](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions)

I have a connection and it insert a stock but not the valuation list.

My copy paste code:

```
var valuation1 = new Valuation
        {
            Price = 15,
            Time = DateTime.Now,
        };

        var valuation2= new Valuation
        {
            Price = 22,
            Time = DateTime.Now,
        };

        var euro = new Stock
        {
            Symbol = "€",
            Valuations = new List<Valuation> { valuation1, valuation2 }
        };

        connection.CreateTable<Stock>();
        connection.CreateTable<Valuation>();

        connection.InsertWithChildren(euro);

        var stockList = c.GetAllWithChildren<Stock>();
```

In Stocklist is a Stock but in Stock is no Valuation :(

usings:

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions;
using TestSQLite.Models;
```

Models:

```
using SQLite.Net.Attributes;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Stock
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(8)]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [OneToMany]      // One to many relationship with Valuation
    public List<Valuation> Valuations { get; set; }
}
using SQLite.Net.Attributes;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;
using System;
public class Valuation
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Stock))]     // Specify the foreign key
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]      // Many to one relationship with Stock
    public Stock Stock { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions what i could do to make it work?

EDIT:
I just tried some things and if i inseret it by my self like this:

```
c.Insert(euro);
        var e = c.Find<Stock>(s => s.Symbol == "€");

        var valuation1 = new Valuation
        {
            Price = 15,
            Time = DateTime.Now,
            StockId = e.StockId,
            Stock = e
        };

        var valuation2 = new Valuation
        {
            Price = 22,
            Time = DateTime.Now,
            StockId = e.StockId,
            Stock = e
        };

        c.Insert(valuation1);
        c.Insert(valuation2);

var stockList = c.GetAllWithChildren<Stock>();
```

i get a correct stock "euro" and valutations in it! What is my mistake at InsertWithChildren? Or is there anything wrong with my models?

Comment: What errors you got?

Comment: i got no error... he ignores the childs and insert just the stock and i dont know why